# In Racket, is "local" unnecessary for nested function definitions?

Tags: namespaces, local, racket

I've been working through the web application example for Racket (http://docs.racket-lang.org/continue/) and it frequently uses the "local" function to define functions that are only used within another function. I'm don't understand why it's necessary though, because nested functions are already local anyway.

To make a toy example, these two functions do exactly the same thing as far as I can tell:

```
(define (times6-v1 x)
  (define (times2 y)
    (* 2 y))
  (* 3 (times2 x)))

(define (times6-v2 x)
  (local
    [(define (times2 y)
       (* 2 y))]
    (* 3 (times2 x))))
```

Either way "times2" can only be accessed within each function, and not in the global namespace. So, why bother using local?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/plt-scheme/PpNLUT4BhSI/ry4UPae5HpYJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'local' form is used in the teaching languages, and pre-dates the existence of internal definitions. So, if you set the language level to "intermediate", you'll see that the version without the 'local' stops working.

The natural next question: why not get rid of local? The fact is that 'local' has some value in the teaching languages, for at least two reasons:

- You can give better error messages when you require students to explicitly state their intent to generate local variables, and
- The stepper would be sad if we changed the teaching languages. :)

Comment: I understand and agree (and upvote), but I wonder if `local` should really be used in the web app tutorial? It's the second tutorial and likely to be read by many non-student newcomers to Racket (and perhaps by relatively fewer students?). It seems unfortunate to keep showing them something they will probably never need to use.

Comment: Since the `let` form is not used anywhere in the tutorial,  I would not be surprised if the code examples in the document were contributed by someone familiar with the student languages. However, given the nesting of modules, perhaps there is a deep seated dependency.

Comment: Thanks John that makes sense. So local doesn't add any extra functionality that isn't already provided by internal definitions? (except easier-to-understand error messages?)

Comment: Yes, I believe the semantics is identical. The documentation also suggests that this is the case. Using the macro stepper, you can see that for common examples, they expand the same way.

Answer (score 2):

In Racket, as opposed to the student languages, `local` allows both syntax and values to be expressed using the same forms as at top-level: eg. `define`. `define-for-syntax`, etc.

See: [racket/local](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/local.html?q=local)

And compare with the [various `let` forms](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html?q=local#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._letrec-values%29%29).